# How to give options for "configure" using yocto recipes?

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, autotools, yocto, recipe

I want write a recipe in yocto to build my custom component. In that i would like to enable some flags according to machine.

eg:

if machine is x86

my configure command should be like :

```
./configure --enable-x86
```

if it is x64

```
./configure --enable-x64
```

i am using auto tools for building. please help me in writing recipe as well as "configure.ac" for achieving this.

ps: I am very new to yocto.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can provide the configure options using ***EXTRA_OECONF***. Here, you can also append values to it based on your architecture.

```
EXTRA_OECONF_append_x86="--enable-x86"
EXTRA_OECONF_append_x64="--enable-x64"
```

You can do this only if your architecture (x86/x64) is defined as aprt of OVERRIDE value. Let us see what *OVERRIDE* value is:

The Yocto bitbake configuration values are defined in *poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf*. In that file, there is a variable called *OVERRIDE*. The sample value for *OVERRIDE* in bitbake configuration is shown below:

```
OVERRIDES = "${TARGET_OS}:${TRANSLATED_TARGET_ARCH}:build-${BUILD_OS}:pn-${PN}:${MACHINEOVERRIDES}:${DISTROOVERRIDES}:${CLASSOVERRIDE}:forcevariable"
```

When you run ***bitbake -e*** and gather the output, the value for OVERRIDE translates into based on your configuration.

```
OVERRIDES="linux:i586:build-linux:pn-defaultpkgname:x86:qemuall:qemux86:poky:class-target:forcevariable:libc-glibc"
```

In your setup, if you can see x86/x64 as part of OVERRIDE value then you can define configure options as described earlier.